# NullReferenceException by getting data from dataGridView to multidimensional string

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have been doing an app to school - Vocabulary Trainer.
I have `dataGridView`, where I keep the vocabulary. 
I want to get the data from `dataGridView` to a multidimensional array. I used this code for it:

```
string[,]word = new string[tableDataGridView.Rows.Count, tableDataGridView.Columns.Count];
for (int x = 0; x < word.GetLenght(0); x++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i< word.GetLenghth(1); i++)
    {
       word[x,i] = tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
    }
{
```

Data save from `dataGridView` to multidimensional array, but the exception: "NullReferenceException was unhandled" is thrown and the piece of code:

```
word[x,i] = tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
```

is highlighted.
I would be glad if someone help me out.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to practice using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger as it executes, you can stop on that line and observe the values at runtime.  Something there is `null`.  When you debug, you can find out what.  Based on that information, you can make adjustments to your code to handle that.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find what is `null` even after debugging

Comment: It's either `tableDataGridView`, or `tableDataGridView.Rows[x]`, or `tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i]`, or `tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value`.  Has to be one of those.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you please tell me what might be null in one of those?

Comment: Well, what *might* be `null` is either `tableDataGridView`, or `tableDataGridView.Rows[x]`, or `tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i]`, or `tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value`.  You need to pause debugging when the error occurs and see which one it is.  Nobody here can debug this on your computer for you.

Comment: I found it, it was `tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value` but I don't know, how to fix it. When I put before  `word[x,i] = tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value.ToString(); ` a condition:  `if (tableDataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[i].Value != null) ` the programm was running and no exception was thrown, but the multidimensional array  `word ` remained empty

Comment: Then it would seem reasonable to conclude that all of those values in your data are null.  You'll have to examine where those values come from and why they *should* have data.  The code in the question doesn't really have anything to do with that.

Comment: I thought about that too but without the condition the values from my data saved to the array. But thank you for you help, I really appreciate that